# Can't access protected members of a class from a subclass defined in a different package

Tags: java, package, protected, access-specifier

I am learning Java using the book Java: The Complete Reference. I am currently at chapter 9 and thus just inroduced to packages. On page 187, it says  **"If you want to allow an element to be seen outside your current package, but only to classes that subclass your class directly, then declare that element protected** ". What I understand from this is, A subclass that resides in a package, say 'B', and extending a class that is defined as public inside another package 'A', having a member named "proc", then in order to make proc available in all subclasses, including subclasses defined outside the current package 'A', I have to mark it as protected. Now have a look at my implementation of the subclass defined inside package 'B':

```
package subapp;
import app.*;

public class Test extends App {

  public Test() { 
      App app = new App();
      System.out.println(app.proc); // error
   }
}
```

I am sure that all the packages (in both the class files) are loaded correctly, "direct" superclass of Test and its non-parameterized constructor, are publicly accessible, proc is marked as protected, and the main() function has no problem there. But I get a runtime exception when running subapp.Test that says "proc has protected access in /superclass path/. Am I getting the book statement wrong or the statement itself is wrong?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052) is a good table illustrating the basics of the `protected` access modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already extending App, so you do not want to create a new App within the constructor. Instead, try something like this if the variable is `protected`.

```
public Test() {
   System.out.println(this.proc);
}
```

The reason it isn't working for you right now is you are making a new `App` within the constructor, and then trying to access that `App`'s `proc` value directly, instead of through inheritance.

If the `proc` value is not correct through this, you might have to set it before the `System.out.println(this.proc);` Or you could call the `super();` constructor before printing the value if the `proc` is getting initialized the the `App` constructor, such as:

```
public App() {
   proc = "test";
}

//.....

public Test() {
   super();
   System.out.println(this.proc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. But why can't I make use of the protected member the way I am doing in my code? I am still "inside" Test (a subclass) right?

Comment: @Devashish You can call `super();` within the constructor if the parent constructor is initializing the variable `proc`. See my edit if that is the case. But the reason it doesn't work for the code you have right now is because even though you are inside `Test`(a subclass), you are trying to access the values of `App` outside of it's access modifier. `protected` values are only accessible to subclasses, so when you extend `App` you get direct access to all `protected` and `public` variables/methods without having to create a new instance of the object

Comment: Thanks...it's clear now :)